# Why some activity intent does not have action

Tags: android, android-intent, action, logcat

Might be a dumb questions, but ...

Normally when you launch an activity you get the following in the logcat output. For example, Wifi setting page:

12-28 16:47:18.125: INFO/ActivityManager(2461): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.wifi.WifiSettings }

But when I open the advanced setting activity, i only get the following

12-28 16:47:34.047: INFO/ActivityManager(2461): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.android.settings/.wifi.AdvancedSettings }

which only has cmp and there is no action. Why is that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My internal activities barely have an action. You only need an action if your activity can do multiple things like "view", "pick", "play", "send". If you have only one basic functionality, you can simply leave it out.